# Storing source files outside project file directory in Visual Studio C++ 2009

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, directory-structure, projects-and-solutions

Visual Studio projects assumes all files belonging to the project are situated in the same directory as the project file, or one underneath it.

For a particular project (in the non-Visual Studio sense) this is not what I want. I want to store the MSVC-specific files in another folder, because there might be other ways to build the application as well, for example with SCons. Also all the stuff MSVC splurts out clutters the source directory.

Example:

```
/source
/scons
/msvc <- here is where I want my MSVC-specific stuff
```

I can add the files, in Explorer, to the `source` directory manually, and then link them in Visual Studio with the project. It's not the end of the world, but it annoys me a bit that Visual Studio tries to dictate the folder structure of my project.

I was looking through the [schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2.aspx) for the project files but realized that this annoying assumption is in the IDE and not the format of the project files.

Do someone know a neater way to solve this than manually linking files to the project from the `source` directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "linking files to the project"? If you have files in differing folders, does "Add existing files..." not work?

Comment: @GMan, yeah it does. I'm just wondering if there's a neater way to do it, so I won't have to do "Add existing files" all the time but more or less tell the project that my stuff is in a certain directory.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm somewhat in the same boat but I've just learned to add them by hand anyway, I don't think there's a way to tell it to watch a folder. I'd love if there were, though.

Comment: I do this on my biggest project so that we have proper `/include` and `/src` folders.  To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to tell VS, even in VS2010, to put specific files in specific folders by default.  However, you _can_ tell VS where to put the file when you create a new file and add it to the project.  Just change the path where it puts the file.

Comment: James McNellis: Thanks, I've taken this path as well, I create them in the include and src dirs in explorer first then drag them to VS. Oh well, not the end of the world. Seems to be many people with this "problem", maybe I should open a issue on Connect.

Comment: @Skurmedel: +1 on opening a Connect issue. Would be nice to have clean root folders.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489127/changing-the-default-source-file-directory-in-visual-studio, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718445/changing-visual-studio-default-path-for-cpp-h-file

Comment: I requested this as a feature: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3641548-add-the-ability-to-set-a-project-s-root-directory

Answer (score 4):

I use this sometimes, pretty sure it's what you want:

- make sure the `Show All Files` option is on in your solution explorer.
- create a symlink that targets your source directory and put the link at the same level as your project, or even lower if you want finer control. The command is `mklink /j target source`

For the example project structure you show, you'd run `mklink /msvc/source /source` and in the project the source directory will show up as if it was in the project dir (well, actually it is). Additional bonus: adding new items through VS also automatically puts them in the right directory.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I shall try it out when I get home.

Answer (score 3):

You can add files with links like this, they are searchable, view-able, but they do not checkout if you try to change them, also visual studio leaves the wildcards in place:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\Database Schema\Views\*.sql">
      <Link>Views\*.sql</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This goes inside the .proj file.