# Changing Visual Studio default path for .cpp, .h file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, projects-and-solutions

I would like Visual Studio to automatically put my .h file in a folder /ProjectPath/include  and my src file in /ProjectPath/src. That way, if I use the "Create class wizard" for instance, it would put the good path by default without me having to change the folder. Anyone know what setting I should change to get this behaviour when I add file ?

Thanks,

Jean-Philippe

Comment: This is not an available option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click on a folder in solution explorer and go to properties, you need to set the Filter property.

For example the `Source Files` folder by default has a filter like this in a C++ project: `cpp;c;cc;cxx;def;odl;idl;hpj;bat;asm;asmx`

Comment: I didn't know that. This seems to only work with Visual Studio filters though (not physical folder)? Unless there is a way to add a physical folder as a filter in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Ya that's only for the folders in the solution.